# how to Prepare crystal report from listview data or listview items

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

i want to prepare crystal report from listview datas. since i'm not familiar with creating reports, help me how to do this...

thanks in advance,
Ulaganathan.N

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: i only added the crystal report window...because i don't know how to prepare crystal report.

Comment: can u please elobrate your question? which database do u use? which ListView u are getting data from ?

Comment: i didn't use any data base, all i need is to prepare crystal report from listview datas(items). i mean i'm generating the listview item on runtime...plase any one help me.